# Where is the second countability of a Riemann surface used in finding an exhaustion of the surface

Tags: general-topology, riemann-surfaces

I'm reading the first chapter (pg 11) Hubbard's *Teichmüller Theory* where we are considering the following construction for a Reimann surface $X$

> Choose a locally finite cover of $X$ by relatively compact open sets $U_{n}$ and smooth partition of unity $\varphi_{n}$ subordinate to this cover. We then have that 
>   $$g(x) := \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}n\varphi_{n}(x)$$
>   is a proper function.

It was shown earlier that all connected Riemann surfaces are second countable and the author points out that second countability was used in the above construction.

**I was wondering if someone could point out explicitly how secound countablity is used here**

Comment: Otherwise you wouldn't have a countable cover consisting of relatively compact open sets.

Comment: Does paracompactness then allow us to find a locally finite refinement of that cover?

Comment: Yes, but for a locally compact and $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff space, one can directly construct a locally finite open cover consisting of relatively compact sets, so that $\overline{U_n} \subset U_{n+1}$ for all $n$ without explicitly using paracompactness.

Comment: Incidentally Riemann surfaces need not be 2nd countable (just take an uncountable disjoint union of open disks); the correct statement is that all connected Riemann surfaces are 2nd countable.